# Can WCF operate within the same process and is there a case for using it that way to enable parts to communicate?

Tags: wcf

Imagine for the sake of this example, an application like a stock ticker. There's an obvious application of WCF in collecting the ticks, perhaps sending them to be saved in a database, but how about internally?

Would/could you use WCF to define and coordinate the communcation between modules of the same application? Our stock ticker has widgets, one shows the last price, one shows a chart updated in as prices change, one shows the difference between the last two prices.

Could all those be coordinated through WCF within the same process? And would you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They could all be coordinated by WCF communication, however, I'm not sure it would be a good idea.  In the example that you gave, I imagine performance (in terms of latency) is key.  In other words, if your stock ticker is being used by a stock broker that is competing to see stock results first, then WCF communication will probably loose when compared to something like .NET events.

This is due primarily, as I understand it, to the fact that WCF is designed to be a cross-process communication mechanism.  In order to accomplish this, it serializes all objects and then marshals the data to another process, even if it is the same process.  I'm not aware of a way to configure WCF so it knows you are speaking to the same process.

If you are in the same .NET process, all public methods are available to call directly.  So there is much less overhead with directly using the objects as opposed to using WCF.

Comment: It's an interesting problem. I usually use an in process bus I hand rolled which coordinates the transmission of messages. It's all done with a mix of threads, delegates and events. There does seem to be scope for WCF to "know" it's in process though, I'll keep digging :)